# CSS Grid Development Environment on Windows

Tags: css, development-environment, css-grid

I wish to upgrade my web site development environment. Currently using Adobe Dreamweaver (out of habit), but need to

- Write HTML/CSS/PHP/MySQL code in an editor with syntax highlighting, code/tag completion, code hints.
- have a browser window that reflects the code window results (on a save). So write HTML/CSS code, save it, and the browser window is updated
- support for major browsers (choose the browser to be used in the display window)
- allow adjust of browser window width to see responsiveness of my code
- supports latest CSS, including CSS Grid and Flexbox
- Windows 10 environment; not interested in adding Linux (WSL)
- will consider an XAMP/WAMP environment for testing of PHP/MySQLi code locally
- free or low-cost programs are preferred (I'm on a limited budget, but will spend the $ for what is needed)

An important part is things running in Windows 10 environment, and the side-by-side display of a code and browser windows in the editor.

I realize this might be an 'opinion' question (and will probably get some downvotes), but need to get some directions to look at. The googles haven't been helpful yet.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need a text editor that can help you to indent your code and highlight your errors ?

Try to take a look at https://code.visualstudio.com/. Vs Code Editor

You can find a lot of extension to help you write code and find errors

Comment: Perhaps. But in addition, I want to easily see the results of whatever code I write in a browser window, without a save/reload process. I just discovered Pineview, which is more what I am looking for; an IDE that will build clean, easily maintained code for web sites.